# Partition Style - MBR or GPT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, storage

I am setting up a new server and I am designing the server for performance over capacity.  Planning the disk partitioning style I would like to use GPT over MBR but am not sure which is best.  I am using SAN attached storage.

Which partition style, MBR or GPT, is better for a SQL Server 2008 R2 implementation?

Answer (score 5):

MBR cannot handle partitions bigger that 2 TB, thus if your partition is bigger than 2 TB you have to use GPT. There is no performance gain as far as I know. It's all about the capacity!